# How to use livereload with express (express generator)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, livereload

I researched livereload. The documentation says that after requiring it I should use it as such:

```
livereload(app)
```

The [example code](https://github.com/mnmly/express-livereload/blob/master/test/app.js) also shows how it's done

```
var express = require('express')
  ....
  , livereload = require('express-livereload');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  .....
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

livereload(app)

app.get('/', routes.index);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

The thing is I am using the express generator. It as an `app.js` file but the file that runs the server is in `bin/www`.That file looks like this

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('books:server');
var http = require('http');
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
...
function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I've removed the error handling methods.

In the above file, I required live reload and tried `livereload(app)` as well as `livereload(server)` and nothing happened

**I did add the relevant script tag in the jade file, and that renders fine.**

For now I am hoping to not have to use gulp/grunt. I am in the process of learning those and here I'm just trying to quickly solve this problem without too much configuration (unless there's no way around it)

Comment: `app.configure` is depreciated in express 4. I'm not familiar with livereload,  but a simpler alternative might be nodemon (just replace `node <command>` with `nodemon <command>` and when it detects a file change it will reload (although it won't reload the browser).